# C# Compiler command in VS2019 (Net Core) exceed 32767 chars

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, compilation, command-line-arguments, visual-studio-2019

(1) Net core installer have not tuning of location NET Core SDK

[image: Net Core SDK Installer]

(2) VS2019 (MS Build) generate in this environment the same compilation command (with length 37153 chars)

[image: C# compilation command]

If I understand, this command too long for CMD.EXE

[image: command too long]

then any Net Core site in this environment  not compiling, even examples from MS documentation and repository

[image: site from MS repository]

How is possible to overcome this issue?

Comment: Do you mean the maximum length limit for path in Windows issue?

Comment: maybe you run into this [issue, too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61931106/1466046). try reinstall/repair .net 3.1 SDK

Comment: I try solve this issue with SUBST command, but unfortunately result of compiling of my code is negative too. Then I found error in my source code and have changed my source code for successful compilation by VS2019 and going away from this restriction. But this is does not cancel problem with restriction of length of compilation parameters that in ordinary NET Core project is exceed maximum length.